# How can I clear the terminal in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I would like to know to how to do in Ruby what I can do with `system("clear")` in C.
I wrote a program like

```
puts "amit"
system("clear")
```

I want the console to be cleared after executing this commnad, but it is not working.

Comment: What operating system are you running Ruby on?

Comment: SCiTE is not a compiler, it's just a text editor.

Answer (score 70):

If you want something that is vaguely portable you can try:

```
system "clear" || system "cls"
```

which will try both `clear` and `cls`

Comment: Please use `||` instead of `or` (See [here](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#no-and-or-or)). The corresponding command would be `system("cls") || system("clear")`

Comment: For the _copy/pasters_ like me this may throw the error:

`syntax error, unexpected string literal, expecting 'do' or '{' or '('`

`system("clear") || system("cls")` fixes that.

Answer (score 30):

Try any of these two in your ruby file:

```
puts `clear`
```

or

```
puts "\e[H\e[2J"
```

Comment: Please use the second one here.  The idea of forking a process just to clear the screen makes my head hurt.  See here for more information: http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm  Also, check out ncurses for more robust control.  But the chance that you'll find a non-ansi terminal these days is pretty much nil.

Answer (score 18):

**Edit: (rereading your question I realize this is not what you are after. I thought you were referring to the IRB. I will leave this here and not delete it as I feel it is can be very useful information)**

---

Ultimately it depends what system you are on.

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> (<- that is a lower case L) will clear the terminal (
<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> on a mac I believe)

this also works in the regular terminal, or the python interprator, or mysql, etc

there are a fair amount of other shortcuts you may like to familiarize yourself with. i found [this](http://wiki.spry.com/Bash_Shortcuts) after a quick google search:

```
CTRL-l - Clears the screen and places the command prompt at the top of the page.
CTRL-r - Starts a search against the command history. Start by typing in what you want to search by then press CTRL-r to see the matches.
CTRL-c - Kills the current running foreground program.
CTRL-z - Stop/sleep the current running foreground program.
CTRL-s - Stops the output to the screen.
CTRL-q - Allows output to the screen.
CTRL-a - Moves the cursor the start of the line
CTRL-e - Moves the cursor to the end of the line
CTRL-f - Moves the cursor 1 character forward
CTRL-b - Moves the cursor 1 character backward
```

not mentioned on that list is that

```
Alt-F moves the curosor one word forward
Alt- B moves the cursor one word back
```

Answer (score 17):

Here is a multiplatform way to do it:

```
Gem.win_platform? ? (system "cls") : (system "clear")
```

Answer (score 10):

A slight variation works:

```
puts "Here's a very long string"
sleep 1
system ("cls")
```

Mark.

Answer (score 7):

#### clear_screen (Ruby 2.7+)

Starting from Ruby 2.7, there is [a build-in and cross-platform way](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/io/console/rdoc/IO.html#method-i-clear_screen) to clear the terminal output:

```rb
require 'io/console'

$stdout.clear_screen # or STDOUT.clear_screen
```

See the difference between `$stdout` and `STDOUT` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6671716/difference-between-stdout-and-stdout-in-ruby).

Answer (score 6):

This should cover windows and OSX/Linux terminals.

```
def method_name
   puts "amit"
   if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /win32|win64|\.NET|windows|cygwin|mingw32/i
      system('cls')
    else
      system('clear')
   end
end
method_name
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use following 
create a ruby file say check.rb like follwing

```
puts "amit"
#system "clear"
```

and run it from console 
   [Salil@localhost Desktop]$ check.rb

o/p

```
[Salil@localhost Desktop]$ ruby check.rb
amit
[Salil@localhost Desktop]$
```

now modify check.rb 
and run it from console

```
puts "amit"
system "clear"
```

o/p

```
[Salil@localhost Desktop]$
```

Answer (score 4):

For windows users:

Just type this below function in your irb window and you are good to go:

Define this function:

```
def cls
  system('cls')
end
```

After defining call this function whenever required.

Comment: This is a great answer for most operating systems, but it sadly doesn't work on things like UNIX :(

Answer (score 4):

You can use **`system("clear")`** or **`system("cls")`** according to the terminal you are going to print.

- If you are using the Windows Command Prompt, use **`system("cls")`**.
- If you are using a Mac or Linux system, just use **`system("clear")`**.

Or you can use **a better way**. Check this example.

```
count = 0

until count == 10
  system("cls") || system("clear")
  print count
  count += 1
  sleep 1
end
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using MAC OS then use:

```
system('clear')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are on a Mac you can clear your terminal window with "Command + K".

Answer (score 1):

A portable, compromized yet often visually satisfying approach that I use is what I call  "crazy <strike>putz</strike> puts":

```
counter=0
until counter == 50
puts " "
counter += 1
end
```

Comment: This is dependent on how large someones screen buffer is set to and is far from efficient but anyways you can also do 50.times { puts " " } for short

Answer (score 1):

Works on UNIX:

```
system("clear")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Pry, It's very simple
Just `.clear`