# When to use $stderr vs STDERR in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ruby $stdout vs. STDOUT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6671716/ruby-stdout-vs-stdout)

Is `STDERR` generally preferred over using `$stderr`, or vice versa?

And what about `STDOUT` vs `$stdout`?

Comment: I think your question has been answered elsewhere: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6671716/ruby-stdout-vs-stdout

Answer (score 22):

To the contrary, using `$stderr` is preferrable.

The reason for that is that `$stderr` as a global variable can be reassigned, while `STDERR` as a constant shouldn't be reassigned (it raises a warning).

Usually they both point to the same standard error file, but in some cases you might want to temporarily redirect all your output somewhere else (for example, to a log file or into a string buffer), in which case you can just reassign `$stderr` and all your code will respect that (if you were smart enough to use `$stderr` instead of `STDERR` in the first place).

Comment: Although I don't know whether the internal functions use `STDERR` or `$stderr`. You may have to perform all writes and reads explicitly, at which point you should use a dedicated other variable.

Comment: @Linux: Which "internal functions" would write to stderr? The only thing that comes to my mind are warnings, which you can eradicate by fixing them.

Comment: Sorry. I meant `STDOUT` and `$stdout` in relation to `puts` and `gets`. Whoops.

Comment: @Linux: You can always use `$stdout.puts` if you want to be explicit, or even better, write a small abstraction layer on top of it.

Comment: I know. But if you want to do it explicitly, it will be clearer to use a dedicated variable. Constantly assigning `$stdout` is not very clear, especially if you don;t know much of the variable.

Comment: Changing $stderr to something other than stderr would be inadvisable. If you don't want output to go to stderr, explicitly redirect somewhere else, don't reassign $stderr. That just seems like basic good practice in any language. This way lies Obfuscated Perl.