# Animated shell output with Ruby

Tags: ruby, shell

I have implemented *Game of Life*.

What I cannot work out is how to print every iteration of the cell array in the shell. I want to make the output appear animated.

Here is my array print code

```
def print_board board
  wipe_screen
  board.each_with_index do |row,y|
    row.each_with_index do |cell,x|
      print cell == 1 ? '*' : ' '
    end
    print "\n"
  end
end
```

and here is the `wipe_screen` method:

```
def wipe_screen
  Board_Height.each do |_|
    # print "\r"
    # $stdout.write "\e[A\e[2K"
  end
end
```

You can see in the commented out bits what I have already tried.

How can I achieve animated output inside the shell?

EDIT:

Allow me to clarify with an example.

It simply prints out each iteration of the *Game of Life* cycle):

```
*  *     * * ** ** 
*** * **  * *  * **
** **** * *  **** * 
** *   **  * **  ** 
*   *  **  *  ***** 
*****  *  **** *   
*****  * * ** *   * 
* ** *** * **   ****
* **  * ** ***** * 
** *  *   * *****   
*            **  * 
**  ****     *** * 
   *** *     *** * 
   *  **     ***** 
      **     ***** 
      **       *   
       **      ****
        **    * * *
     ****   * *****
     *      ****   
*            **  * 
*   ****     *** * 
   *** *     *** * 
      **     ***** 
      **       *** 
      **       *** 
       ***     * **
       * *     ****
     *****  ** ****
     *      ****   
*            **  * 
    ****     *** * 
    ** *     *** * 
      **       *** 
      **       *** 
      **       *** 
       ***     * **
       * *       **
     *****  ***  **
     *      ****   
             **  * 
    ****     *** * 
    ** *       * * 
      **       *** 
      **       *** 
      **       *** 
       ***     ** *
       * *        *
     *****  ****  *
     *      ****
```

Whereas what I want is:

```
*  *     * * ** ** 
*** * **  * *  * **
** **** * *  **** * 
** *   **  * **  ** 
*   *  **  *  ***** 
*****  *  **** *   
*****  * * ** *   * 
* ** *** * **   ****
* **  * ** ***** * 
** *  *   * *****
```

Then, as it iterates over the game of life cycle, replaced by:

```
  *      ****   
          **  * 
  ****     *** * 
  ** *       * * 
   **       *** 
   **       *** 
   **       *** 
    ***     ** *
    * *        *
  *****  ****  *
  *      ****
```

EDIT:

game of life [gist](https://gist.github.com/Thermatix/54bda5fc4d2d92e6a939)

Comment: how about one of those ways? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170553/how-can-i-clear-the-terminal-in-ruby

Comment: just tried them, none of them work. they just print out a massive gap on the in the shell and then the next iteration rather than printing out the next iteration over the previous print array

Comment: Ok, then curses will help you: http://ablogaboutcode.com/2013/04/01/overwriting-console-output-using-curses-in-ruby/

Comment: Could you post your complete runnable code somewhere (gist.github.com, for example) so that we can see if it works on our machines? (keywords: complete and runnable)

Comment: BTW, have you tried _all_ of them? There are many ways in that post.

Comment: I did, they either did nothing or print a giant gap without actually clearing the previously printed array.

Comment: What's your environment (os, shell, ruby version)?

Comment: osx, zsh, 2.2.3p173, also find gist in OP.

Comment: yeah, none of them work. Try that curses thing, though. It's the industry standard for printing to terminal in arbitrary positions.

Comment: Is that really the only way? It feels like using a bazooka to swat a fly.

Comment: @Thermatix you are using `"\e[A\e[2K"`, correct control sequence is `"\e[A\e[2J"` as in the linked answer...

Comment: @Thermatix: it's the only working way to overwrite multiple lines that I know of. Posted a comment to your gist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an animated look, do not wipe the screen, but return the cursor to the home position. At least in bash and tcsh, you may achieve that with

```
print "\033[0;0H]"
```

Then continue and overwrite the updated cell contents.
Use `STDOUT.flush` at the end of the page to empty the output buffer.

Comment: That's fairly close to what I want, how does it work? specifically,how to make it below the input line?

Comment: This is not a Ruby issue, but shell specific. Have a look at Cursor movement in the shell documentation, e.g.: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html .

Comment: Just fairly close? You can move the cursor to any location. Just replace 0;0 with your coordinates.