# How can i use Commands from more then one operating- system in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, linux, windows, macos

In Windows I have to use `cls` to clear the Console, in Linux just `clear`!

Is there a Function like:

`system("cls")` or `system("clear")`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I clear the terminal in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170553/how-can-i-clear-the-terminal-in-ruby/)

Comment: Oh, it doesn't seem to have a good answer. Unless you want to install the `curses` gem, use [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code): `print "\e[H\e[2J"`. It's not as portable though.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, an already written method for both does not exists in ruby native libs. However, you can do something like that :

```
module OS
  def OS.windows?
    (/cygwin|mswin|mingw|bccwin|wince|emx/ =~ RUBY_PLATFORM) != nil
  end

  def OS.mac?
   (/darwin/ =~ RUBY_PLATFORM) != nil
  end

  def OS.unix?
    !OS.windows?
  end

  def OS.linux?
    OS.unix? and not OS.mac?
  end
end
```

then :

```
def clear_console
    if OS.windows?
      system("cls")
    else
      system("clear")
    end
end
```

credit goes to [Aaron Hinni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12086/aaron-hinni) for the `OS` module.