# Clear screen before any output to console

Tags: ruby, output, highline

I use [HighLine](https://github.com/JEG2/highline) gem for UI. I want to [clear the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170553/how-can-i-clear-the-terminal-in-ruby) before output any data. Which method should I use? [Patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513558/executing-code-for-every-method-call-in-a-ruby-module) some Ruby methods like `puts`? Patch HighLine? Change my app in some way? At the moment it has `Dialog` class with various methods which call HighLine functions for interacting with user. Or maybe HighLine has a built-in method to do that?

Comment: `puts "\e[2J"`.

Comment: My question is not about clear-screen method itself. It is about where should I put this code and how to do it right way. But thanks for the hint.

Comment: “where should I put this code”—where you need the screen to be cleared.

Comment: It should be cleared before any output as I said.

Comment: Really? `puts 'Q.: Please enter a number'; puts '>'` ⇐ do you really want the screen to be cleared _twice_ (one in between of puts?) Any output is chunked, according to some business rules, and you are the only person who understands these business rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the requirements are not clear and I won’t recommend this way, but the stated problem might be solved with:

```
$stdout.singleton_class.prepend(Module.new do
  def write(string)
    super("\e[2J" << string)
  end
end)
```

I think, this answer is not suitable for the OP, but *it perfectly answers the exact question asked*.

Comment: Yes, you are quite right. It is exactly what I ask for and it is not what I want absolutely. I should manually clear screen in right places of **my app** according to business logic.