# How to use Ctrl-L to clear Rails pry or irb console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, irb, pry

`Ctrl-l` doesn't seem to work, neither does `clear`.

The only way I've found is to run `system('clear')` which I find clunky.

Is there a way to get the same `Ctrl-l` functionality in the terminal inside the rails console?

Edit:

I put the following in my `~/.pryrc`:

```
def c
  system 'clear'
end
```

Which is working.

But why does `Ctrl-l` work on Rails 4 but not Rails 5?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I clear the terminal in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170553/how-can-i-clear-the-terminal-in-ruby)

Comment: Search on "ruby clear console" for many past proposed solutions, none much better than what you have FWIW.

Comment: This is not a duplicate question and is not an issue in Ruby the language. I'm having the same issue with the Rails 5 console. `Ctrl+l` works properly in IRB (MRI v2.3.1), but in the Rails 5 console it opens a new line in the REPL without clearing the screen as expected.