# How do I clear the screen in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, rubymine

I really need to know how to clear the screen in Ruby. I've already looked all over and haven't found anything that can help.

I've already tried using cls in several formats and it NEVER worked (I am on Windows, btw).

All that happens is an arrow keeps showing up in the IRB console.

Comment: which os are you using, `cls` is for windows, for linux or osx it should be `system('clear')`

Comment: I'm using Windows and like I said, cls didn't work.

Comment: What is "the screen"? The console of rubymine? Or in the shell (command.com, powershell...)? If it is in the shell, then `cls`should work. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170553/how-can-i-clear-the-terminal-in-ruby

Comment: Where the program runs when you test it is what I mean.

Answer (score 3):

To clear the terminal window on multiple operational systems, you could use:

```
def clear
  if Gem.win_platform?
    system 'cls'
  else
    system 'clear'
  end
end
```

> [Documentation for **Gem#win_platform?**](https://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_125/Gem/win_platform%3F/class)
>   Is this a windows platform?

Comment: I already said that 'cls' doesn't work and I AM on Windows. All it's doing is having some arrow shape show up in the IRB console. It's not clearintg anything.

Answer (score 0):

I found out earlier today that 'cls' doesn't work in RubyMine but it will work if I run the app in command prompt. It would've been nice if I had been told about that earlier.

Answer (score -1):

on terminal type 'clear' and  hit enter button it will clear your screen .

Comment: Clear the screen using Ruby